# How pressing tab twice listing directories and files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm wondering how pressing tab twice is resulting in listening all the files and directories in Linux. I'm specifically interested in where this function is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function is called [Command Line Completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_completion) and is well documented on the Internet.

How it is defined and configured is dependent on which shell you are using.